# How to use the official Flutter gallery

Tags: flutter

Im totally new to flutter, and would like to try out the official examples gallery: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery

I´ve installed Android studio and have the emulator running, which works great when i start the demo app from VS code.

Problem is, how do i fetch the gallery app, and load it onto the virtual device? The simple guide says I should run these two commands:

```
flutter packages get
flutter run --release
```

This does not work, as the terminal throws this error: "Release mode is not supported for emulators." If I instead run

```
flutter run --debug
```

it loads up the "You have pushed the button x this many times" standard demo app. And i really cant see how these two commands tells the terminal to get the flutter gallery.
I´ve also tried to change the flutter channel to dev, but this dosent help.
Flutter doctor says everything is OK.

So how do I you try out the official flutter gallery app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch to the project directory of the gallery app first

```
cd your_flutter_install_dir/examples/flutter_gallery
flutter packages get
flutter run
```

If you have a real device connected (and the emulator closed) you can also use `flutter run release`